# Не запускается виртуальная машина debian

Tags: linux, vmware

00:03:43.393103 000000000033fc18: 00007ffe995017f0 - 0x000e17f0 bytes into C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll - последняя строка журнала
инструкция по адресу 0х00000 written и бла бла

Comment: Блабла - обычно самое интересное

Comment: @eri ну там всё нули и written